# Meteor js - React vs Blaze, какие преимущества?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, redux, meteor

1. Конечно, я нетерпеливый, просматривая руководство Meteor + React пока вижу лишь одни недостатки перед использованием Blaze. Объясните, пожалуйста, пока я сам это не понял, в чём преимущества?
2. Если найдётся минутка [другая] объясните также, чем React лучше Vue и можно ли обойтись Reactom без Vue и наоборот?
3. React можно использовать с Redux. То, что мне известно о Redux достаточно, чтобы понять его полезность. Обычно Redux в интернете встречается вместе с React, так вот, можно ли как то без React и, может быть, в Vue уже есть что-то получше?

Искренне извиняюсь за нетерпеливую любознательность.

Answer (score 1):

1. Основное преимущество `React` перед `Blaze` состоит в том, что `React` одна из самых известных в мире библиотек для создание UI, а Blaze это библиотека UI только для Meteor, причем не самая популярная даже тут. Как результат для `React` есть куча библиотек, документации, огромное сообщество, быстрое решение проблем, активное развитие и т.д. и т.п. У Blaze этого всего нет.
2. Какая библиотека `React` или `Vue` лучше вопрос спорный и каждый тут выбирает что лучше для него. Библиотеки являются аналогами и лучше выбрать какую-то одну, хотя, наверное, можно использовать и обе, но зачем?
3. `Redux` просто подход к работе с данными в приложении, соответственно может быть использован с любой библиотекой. Конкретно у `Vue` есть `Vuex`, вероятно, есть и другие библиотеки.

Comment: По своему опыту: по Blaze очень тяжело найти решение проблемы/задачи. Я часто даже не знаю, существует ли такое решение. По React все обычно находится по 1-2 ссылке.